# Find out which players I've already met

Tags: c#, data-modeling

I have the following data structure:

```
public class Match
{

    public List<Player> Participants;

}

public class Player
{

    public string Name;

}
```

Now I got the following sample data:

```
Match 1
 - PlayerA
 - PlayerB
 - PlayerC

Match 2
 - PlayerA
 - PlayerB
 - PlayerD
 - PlayerE
```

According to this data if `PlayerA` would want to know with which players he played the answer would be `PlayerB, PlayerC, PlayerD and PlayerE`.

My question is now what the would be the most logic and easy-to-query data structure if I want to show **which player played with whom** and **how often**. After all I want to show the user a chart like this (uber paint skills):

[image: Chart]

Comment: Have each player maintain a `List<T>` of the name/Id of  those they have met.  For *how often*, `T` would have to include a counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a suggestion to make your solution neater, have Player override Equals. The code looks like this:

```
public class Player
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Player;
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        return this.Name == other.Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public string Name;
}
```

This allows you to make a much more readable opponent-finding solution, along the lines of this

```
Player me = new Player { Name = "Me" };
var allMatches = new List<Match>
{
    new Match
    {
        Participants = new List<Player> 
        {
            me,
            new Player { Name = "Some Other Dude"}
        }
    },

    new Match
    {
        Participants = new List<Player>
        {
            me,
            new Player { Name = "My Rival" }
        }
    }
};

var myMatches = allMatches.Where(m => m.Participants.Contains(me)).ToList();
var myOpponents = myMatches.SelectMany(m => m.Participants.Except(new [] {me})).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, using `Linq`

```
List<List<Match> matches = ...
string player = "playerA";

var coplayers = matches.Where(x=>x.Any(p=>p.Participants.Any(s=>s.Name == player))) // get all participants where group contains participant.
           .SelectMany(x=> x.SelectMany(p=>p.Participants))                         // get all participants where group contains participant.
           .Where(x=>x.Name != player)                                              // List co participants 
           .GroupBy(x=>x.Name)                                                      // Distinct by grouping on Name or( need to override equal)
           .Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault())
           .ToList()
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ynEfmy)